# Angular 7 and material page event on paginator is only showing one new row when page index is changed

Tags: mysql, angular, limit, angular7, paginator

I am using `(page)` event on `<mat-paginator>`:

```
<mat-paginator #paginator 
      [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100, 1000]" 
      [pageSize]="pageSize" [showFirstLastButtons]="true"
      [length]="total" (page)="getData($event)" 
      *ngIf="total>0">
</mat-paginator>
```

To change the data displayed in a `<mat-table>`.

When a user change the page number of using arrows to back and forward, the `(page)` event is fired:

```
getData(e)
{
  //this.oldPageSize = e.pageSize
  //console.log(e.pageIndex+' '+e.pageSize )
  this.getKits('defined', e.pageIndex, e.pageSize);
}
```

`getKits()` will go to server and the following script will be executed:

```
$sql = 'SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM kit) as total, kit_id as id, kit_name as name,
    type_of_kit as ktype, received_quantity as quantity, kit_status as kstatus, date_added as da
    FROM kit
    ORDER BY system_date DESC 
    LIMIT :p, :s
    ';

$exec = $conn->prepare($sql);
$exec->bindValue(':p', $page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$exec->bindValue(':s', $size, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$exec->execute();
$res = $exec->fetchAll();
```

On component load, the `pageIndex` and `pageSize` are `0` and `5`. And when the `getData(e)` is fired, they will be changed.

The problem is that, when the first initial data are loaded (5 rows), and when I go to next page of paginator, it will be `getKits('defined', 1, 6)` and only one new row is shown at the bottom, and one old row is removed from it.

What I need is to show the next 5 rows. Maybe next 10 rows. (Here the number is about the size selected).

Comment: Multiply the page index by the page size ?

Comment: That's it. I wa trying some simple logic and math on it to figure it out. Thanks. @trichetriche

Comment: Well no problem